# How to install Android Studio in silent mode?

Tags: installation, android-studio, silent-install

We are trying to install Android Studio (android-studio-bundle->Version-ID<-windows.exe) in silent mode.

So far I could find no hint which commandline Switches are avaiable for this installer. Only the [following posting](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=101303).

Any idea how to install this package in silent mode and which switches are available for this installer?

Comment: Does running the installer with the `/?` option from the commandline give you any options? `/s` is the default for silent installs.  Oh how about this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918329/silent-install-of-android-studio

Answer (score 1):

We got to know that Android Studio uses the NSIS installer on Windows.

You can find the command line options for this installer [here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter3.html#installerusagecommon)

/? is not working.

And some restrictions are known as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918329/silent-install-of-android-studio)